# Xdebug doesn't show profiler output on OS X Lion

Tags: php, profiling, osx-lion, xdebug

I am trying to get the Xdebug profiler on OS X Lion to output files like it's supposed to, but it won't. I can debug OK and code coverage also works, but I cannot get it to output the cachegrind files.

Relevant section of my php.ini:

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /var/log/xdebug
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%R"

include_path=".:/usr/lib/php/pear"
magic_quotes_gpc=off
date.timezone = 'Europe/Berlin'
extension = memcached.so
extension = http.so
memory_limit=1G
```

Comment: Can the user php is running as create files in /var/log/xdebug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things I can think off:

1. The user under which PHP runs can't write files to /var/log/xdebug
2. The filename it's trying to generate (you use %R after all!) is too large for the filesystem to understand. Try using the default for `xdebug.profiler_output_name`.

Comment: It was the second one, I never realized that of course the url (and thus the filename) could get that long :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MAMP, there is also a third way: you are modifying the wrong php.ini file.

As i just discovered and posted here: [Where does MAMP keep its php.ini?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691767/where-does-mamp-keep-its-php-ini/24633893#24633893)

Hoping this can help.