# Where does MAMP keep its php.ini?

Tags: macos, mamp, php

I have recently got a mac an am not used to developing on a mac at all.

I have MAMP Pro 1.9.6.1. I did a locate on `php.ini` and got this:

```
$ locate php.ini
/Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.2/php.ini
/Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.3/php.ini
/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini
/private/etc/php.ini.default
```

I changed the name of all of them. Restarted MAMP. It loaded without a hitch (I know odd right?). I am using PHP version 5.2.

All of these files are now different names (done one by one for process of elimination).
So I figure restart the mac. Same, MAMP loaded no problems, even though all of the `php.ini` files had been move. On Lamp this that wouldn't even load. But either there is another `php.ini` file I'm missing (quite possible I don't know how to `updatedb`), MAMP is really intelligent and just pulls in all of them (less likely) or it doesn't use one.

Comment: MAMP Pro uses dynamic generated `php.ini`. You have to edit the template.

Comment: Ricardo Martins Should be the right answer James...

Comment: I'm using MAMP 4 (free) and my php.ini path is `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.1/conf/php.ini`

Comment: I have found php.ini file at /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.0.0/conf/php.ini Note: Do not forget to restart apache is my made any changes in php.ini file, otherwise you will not get made changes updates on server. Thanks :)

Answer (score 149, accepted):

**Note:** If this doesn't help,  check below for Ricardo Martins' answer.

---

Create a PHP script with `<?php phpinfo() ?>` in it, run that from your browser, and look for the value `Loaded Configuration File`.  This tells you which `php.ini` file PHP is using in the context of the web server.

Comment: Its pulling from here /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini but it seams to reload it every startup

Comment: That should be the file to edit to make changes then.  Are you not seeing changes you make there?  Then read this good historical article on developing on OSX ;) http://web.archive.org/web/20110331152508/http://teddziuba.com/2011/03/osx-unsuitable-web-development.html

Comment: This is not very helpful actually as MAMP overwrites the file before server start.

Comment: or you can even run `echo '<?php phpinfo() ?>'|php` from the terminal.

Comment: Or just `php -i` (easier to read and shorter than `echo '<?php phpinfo() ?>'|php`).  Note: sometimes the console version of php uses a different `php.ini` file and may have different settings than the CGI or Apache PHP.

Comment: on the mamp panel at localhost you can just click php.info from the menu

Comment: Needs server restart to apply php.ini changes.

Comment: I had to restart MAMP app, not just the servers to apply, anyway phpInfo is in main menu of WebStart page, there is the place I have copied the path to active php.ini.. happy coding :)

Comment: I've followed all these steps, none of them worked for me In my phpinfo page I can see the updated values, but my laravel application still throws error the file "Intro01.mp4" exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive (limit is 2048 KiB).

I use php verison 7.2.8 /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.8/conf/php.ini -- this is the url as given to me by my phpinfo page Now I'm confused, what is wrong?

Comment: I did not have a `php.ini` in the location described in `info.php`, but two templates as `php.ini-dev` and `-prod`. I had to create a `php.ini` at the same location using these and I did so. Now it works!

Answer (score 78):

I'm not sure if in MAMP (non-PRO) is the same, but MAMP overrides the modified `php.ini` everytime it starts.

In my case, I needed to use the MAMP menu to change my `php.ini file` (`File -> Edit Template -> PHP -> PHP 5.xx -> php.ini`).

Comment: MAMP (non-Pro) v2.2 doesn't have seem to have this option (or a File menu)

Comment: @tedmiston: If you do not see the File Menu, you might have activated the "hide dock-symbol"-option. If you disable this, you´re able to see the file menu again.

Comment: @tt_de I've got the dock icon shown, but even in v3, my menu bar reads: "MAMP, Edit, Servers, Tools, Help".  Any chance you're on a Linux machine?  Perhaps they put the MAMP menu items under File on non-OS X platforms.  Nonetheless, I don't have "Edit Template" in any menu, but I can edit the files manually from the file system.

Comment: @tedmiston: Sorry, I´m on a OS X!

Comment: @tt_de I am as well.  Strange.

Comment: This should be the correct answers. Works on MAMP PRO as well.

Comment: verified working on MAMP Pro - El Capitan - fresh installation. after an hour of googling, this answer provided the correct course of action. +1 @Ricardo Martins

Comment: It doesn't appear to be overwriting values I've changed. In particular the auto_start for sessions.

Answer (score 39):

To be clearer (as i read this thread but didn't SEE the solution, also if it was here!), I have the same problem and found the cause: I were modifying the wrong php.ini!

Yes, there are 2 php.ini files in MAMP:

1. Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.5.10/php.ini
2. Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/conf/php.ini

The right php.ini file is the second: Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/conf/php.ini

To prove this, create a .php file (call it as you like, for example "info.php") and put into it a simple phpinfo()

```
<?php
echo phpinfo();
```

Open it in your browser and search for "Loaded Configuration File": mine is "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/conf/php.ini"

The error was here; i edited Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.5.10/php.ini but this is the wrong file to modify! Infact, the right php.ini file is the one in the bin directory.

Take care of this so small difference that caused me literally 1 and a half hours of headaches!

Comment: The exact directory depends on which PHP version you are using, but yeah, that path (../MAMP/bin/php/phpX/conf/php.ini) is correct. I also edited the php.ini.temp file just in case. Set display_errors = On in both cases.

Comment: This is the answer I needed since I do not have the Pro version.

Comment: MAMP 5 doesn't have conf folders in the bin/php folders anymore.

Answer (score 22):

The file you have to edit is in MAMP Pro and uses the `php.ini` file everytime it starts up.

- Start MAMP PRO
- Edit `File > Edit Templates > PHP 5.3.2 php.ini`
- Restart MAMP Pro

Your changes should stick.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know if you ever found an answer to this but I DIDN'T need MAMP PRO to do this.  Simply goto the correct path by following what others have said. It's something like...

> MAMP-> bin-> php-> php(your php version)-> conf-> php.ini

The key here is where you're editing the file.  I was making the mistake of editing the commented part of the ini file.  You actually have to scroll down to LINE #472 where it says "display_errors = Off and change it to On.  Hope this helps any

Answer (score 6):

Just run the following command from your terminal, it will show you your **Loaded Configuration File** easiest way I have ever found.

```
php --ini
```

Answer (score 2):

Change /Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.2/php.ini if you are using 5.2 version of php. If you are using the 5.3 php version, edit the /Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.3/php.ini.

If you are using OSX Lion or OSX Mountain Lion, I recommend you using the default installation of apache and php.

Greets!

Comment: I think MAMP is a better option than the default because it includes multiple versions of PHP as well as a few precompiled [PHP Accelerators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_accelerator).  Apple has kindly [removed the Web Sharing preference](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5230?viewlocale=en_US) in Mountain Lion :(.  Also note that the MAMP 2.x paths for PHP include the minor version (eg `MAMP/conf/php5.4.3`).

Answer (score 2):

After running the MAMP server, you have php info link in toolbar 
Once click, You will get all information about php 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which version of PHP your MAMP is using. You can find it out on: `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf` looking for the configured `php5_module`.

After that, as someone said before, you have to go to the `bin` folder. There you'll find a `conf` folder with a `php.ini` inside.

example: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/conf`

Leo

Answer (score 1):

Probably the fastest way to access the PHP.ini for the currently loaded version of PHP in MAMP PRO (v.4.2.1):

1. Open MAMP Pro
2. Click on "PHP" under the "Languages" section on the sidebar
3. Tap on the arrow button right next to the drop-down that lets you select the "Default Version" of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

After going through all the solutions here, the easiest way to find the loaded `php.ini` file is to go into `phpinfo` on the loaded MAMP webpage, which will show you the loaded php.ini file.

This will also confirm if the parameters you change, like max_file_size, have updated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

On my Mac, running MAMP I have a few locations that would be the likely `php.ini`, so I edited the `memory_limit` to different values in the 2 suspected files, to test which one effected the actual MAMP PHP INFO page details.
By doing that I was able to determine that this was the correct `php.ini`:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.10/conf/php.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

I only have the non-pro version of MAMP but just because it loads it doesn't mean the PHP file is being found/without errors.

I renamed my `php.ini` files and MAMP still started but Apache returned several errors.

What are you trying to change in your `php.ini` file?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked all answers and of course I have used phpinfo() to check the exact location of php.ini. I don't see a File option in the menu bar on my mac. I changed both php.ini and php.ini.temp files in that folder. No vail.

Until I realized that I forgot to uncomment the modified always_populate_raw_post_data line.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this too. My changes weren't being reflected in phpInfo.  It wasn't until I stopped my servers and then restarted them again that my changes actually took effect.