# Warning: get_headers() This function may only be used against URLs in

Tags: php, localhost, get-headers

I want to check if an external url exists and I've tried using different functions. Most functions use get_headers() function and this always shows me the warning "Warning: get_headers () [function.get-headers]: This function May only be used against URLs in / myhosting/..." . What could be the cause that this does not work?
Localhost, Mac with MAMP

Comment: I was using the function of http://stackoverflow.com/a/15617151/1504078

Comment: I am sorry for this question. I found a error in my code

Answer (score 6):

Check the following setting in your php.ini file. It should be On.

allow_url_fopen = On; (the php doc : [allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen))

You can look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691767/where-does-mamp-keep-its-php-ini) on how to edit your php.ini