# Is there a php.ini in tidesdk?

Tags: php, configuration-files, ini, tidesdk

I can't find any `php.ini` file in php module, does it exist elsewhere ? Do we need to use only the ini_set() function ?

Comment: As a general tip, if you use the `phpinfo();` command, it'll state which .ini file is currently in use.

Comment: Okay, it says `Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /opt/php/lib`. But what's the absolute path ?

Comment: Er... that is an absolute path.

Comment: It doesn't look like in my opinion. If it was absolute I would have an "opt" folder in my HD root, which I don't have. I guess the php.ini path is relative to the current php installation directory. Then I've to find where is the tidesdk php coming from...

Comment: I see what you mean, but the presence of the initial forward slash would imply otherwise. (Also, I'm getting the full root path when I run it myself. Then again, perhaps MAMP is different.) Incidentally, if you run php via the command line, what does `php --ini` show?

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691767/where-does-mamp-keep-its-php-ini *might* have some bearing on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your using a bundle application, also depending on OS it should be in the PHP folder.
for me since I'm using WAMP is in

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php(version)
```

look where your php application was installed.

Comment: I'm on mac with MAMP by the way. How would I know which php version tidesdk is using ?

Comment: Look within one of these 2 directory     /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/conf/php.ini
or
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/php.ini

Comment: @MoisesHidalgo is your answer related to TideSDK? I have bundled apps without any instance of php on my local computer so I am under the impression your answer is irrelevant to the OP's question.