# Editing php.ini with MAMP 3.5 where is the right ini file?

Tags: php, mamp

I'm trying to edit my php.ini file to turn off short tags.  Pretty standard.

`phpinfo()` tells me I am running PHP Version 5.6.10

I have edited 2 php.ini files so far, and neither has taken effect (yes, I restarted MAMP)

```
MAMP/conf/php5.6.10/php.ini

MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/conf/php.ini
```

Neither file changes the status of short tags

Can anyone direct me where/how to change my php.ini settings?

I really freaking miss WAMP.  Whose bright idea was it to buy a Mac?!?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does MAMP keep its php.ini?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691767/where-does-mamp-keep-its-php-ini)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaannnnnnnnddddd I was being a dufus

I had been commenting the line out instead of changing to "Off"

Comment: You may want to simply close the question then.

Comment: John, takes 2 days before I am allowed to close the question, sometimes these things are forgotten...

@eric-leschinski, this does provide an answer (I was using the wrong syntax), and I AM the OP....

Answer (score 2):

When you run `phpinfo()` you need to look for the value `Loaded Configuration File`. This tells you **which** `php.ini` file PHP is using in the context of the web server.

Comment: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/conf/php.ini

Which has short_open_tags commented out

Comment: @Sanfly, are you using MAMP Pro?

Answer (score 1):

On my Mac, running MAMP I have a few locations that would contain the likely php.ini
So I edited the memory_limit to different values in the 2 suspected files,
to test which one effected the actual MAMP PHP INFO page details.
By doing that I was able to determine that this was the correct php.ini:
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.10/conf/php.ini

Answer (score 0):

as you version is 5.6.10, and supposed your apache2 server runing on ubuntu.
php.ini dir is

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```