# How can I show PHP error instead of giving me 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache, mamp

I want to display specific error not just returns a 500 internal server error.

I configured php.ini file like this;

```
display_errors = On

display_startup_errors = On

error_reporting = E_ALL
```

And restarted server but it just gives me a 500 internal server error...

Comment: Make sure you edit the right `php.ini`, look here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691767/where-does-mamp-keep-its-php-ini

Comment: Just to verify what catcon suggested, create a simple empty .php file with one line only: <?php phpinfo(); ?> and access it. Check your values there to see if your configuration actually have all relevant options properly set.

Comment: Yes, that told me configuration file is here;
 /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.8/conf/php.ini
and I edited that file. So the problem is something else I think