# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver - windows MAMP php. The PHP.ini file has the correct part uncommented

Tags: php, mysql, windows, mamp

I have the below error -

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver
```

When trying to connect via PDO.

```
<?php


$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'mytodo';
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'root';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$options = [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
try {
     $pdo = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}

require ('index.view.php');
```

I've gone through countless instances of the same issue and all were resolved by uncommenting the "extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll" in php.ini, but it has made no difference for me.

I'm using Windows 10, MAMP and PHP 8.0.1

phpinfo() is showing no drivers under PDO

[image: PDO drivers]

despite being uncommented in php.ini

[image: php.ini]
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I would run a test php page that displays `phpinfo();` to double-check that the PDO mysql extension is in fact loaded. You remember that you need to restart the http server after editing php.ini, right?

Comment: Hi @BillKarwin, thanks for this - Yes I've even restarted the entire PC. How do I do as you suggested? I'm new to PHP/backend in general.

Comment: @BillKarwin I've worked it out (literally run a page with phpinfo() lol) - there's novalue showing in the PDO drivers. Is there more I need to do other than uncomment them in the php.ini?

Comment: Does the phpinfo output tell you which php.ini it is using? A common mistake is to edit the wrong copy of php.ini.

Comment: @BillKarwin it doesn't, in Configuration File (php.ini) Path: its "no value" again

Comment: Well that would explain why your change to the php.ini file didn't fix the issue. https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-Windows/FAQ/index.html says the php.ini file is in `C:\MAMP\conf\phpX.XX` (I assume X.XX means a filename corresponding to the PHP version). Was that the file you edited?

Comment: It was, yes. Does this mean its not detecting a php ini file at all?

Comment: I've just checked the other php.ini files and they all have the correct part uncommented already too

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/16154605/20860 and other answers on that thread.

Comment: I tried this - its for mac only and ricardo's answer doesnt apply, and the one marked as correct answer above it doesn't work as there's no value in my "Loaded Configuration File"

Comment: Okay, I'm out of ideas. I don't use Windows.

Comment: I *think* I may have fixed it. I copied the php.ini from the original location into the php 8.0.1 folder and restarted MAMP. The loaded configuration file now has a path (the new file). I'll let you know if it worked!

Comment: Yes! Thanks for all of your help @BillKarwin, very much appreciated.

Comment: You might want to summarize the solution by posting an answer, so people who find this by searching will benefit more easily than by reading this long thread of comments. This also gets this question out of the "Unanswered questions" queue.

Comment: Already have! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if this is the correct way to fix this issue, but it worked so i'm guessing so?

Turns out the location listed in the MAMP documentation isn't the one I was looking for `C:\MAMP\conf\phpX.XX` - It was in fact `C:\MAMP\bin\php\phpX.X.X`. The issue I had after realising this is that there WASN'T a php.ini file in here, which is the reason I assumed it to be the other location. I then copied the .ini from the `C:\MAMP\conf\phpX.XX` location, and restarted MAMP. Boom.